# How to fix - cannot encode object: 28.0, of type: <class 'PIL.TiffImagePlugin.IFDRational'>?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to serialize EXIF metadata from a JPEG file using `pillow` in python3. The metadata are being extracted using `my_jpeg_image._getexif()` (perhaps there is a better way).

When I try to serialize* those data, I receive the error

```py
cannot encode object: 28.0, of type: <class 'PIL.TiffImagePlugin.IFDRational'>
```

Why is a `TiffImagePlugin` class being used by pillow for *JPEG* metadata extraction?

How can I convert a `IFDRational` to a serializable type e.g. `float`/`int` in this case (and/or in general)?

Thanks!

[*FWIW, into mongodb]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an IFDRational object `obj` to type float, you can do

```
number = obj._numerator / obj._denominator
```

```
print(type(number))
```

Now it becomes  `<class 'float'>`

However, if the *denominator* is 0 , you may need to handle it exceptionally.

IFDRational details are below:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.html